# gdb отладка многопоточного приложения

Tags: c++, linux, c, gdb

здравствуйте, возникла необходимость научиться отлаживать многопоточное приложение через gdb... предположим, есть такое приложение с несколькими потоками:

```
int main() {
     static int i =0;
     std::thread([](){ while(true) { ++i; std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds(700)); std::cout << "hello\n";}}).detach();
     std::thread([](){ while(true) { std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(600)); std::cout << "my\n";}}).detach();
     std::thread([](){ while(true) { std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(900)); std::cout << "world\n";}}).detach();
     std::thread([](){ while(true) { std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(700)); std::cout << "ro\n";}}).join();
}
```

подключаемся gdb -p number_of_pid процесс:

```
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
Attaching to process 9208
[New LWP 9209]
[New LWP 9210]
[New LWP 9211]
[New LWP 9212]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
0x00007f1bae990acd in pthread_join () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
```

и приложение останавливается... подскажите как увидеть в отладчике значение переменной i, если как только присоединяемся gdb, то все останавливается, а если делаем next, потом, предположим, br в какой-то строке, затем далее n, то все идет по-прежнему, значение переменной i(через print) вывести не удается...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Базовые заметки молодой хозяйке

Для отладки (по крайней мере для комфортной отладки) необходимо собирать с отладочной информацией, в gcc для этого используется ключ `-g`:

```
g++ -pthread -g thr.cpp -o thr
```

Можно либо сразу запустить процесс под gdb:

```
gdb ./thr
```

либо привязаться к уже запущенному процессу:

```
gdb -p <pid_of_already_running_process>
```

В первом случае, после запуска отладчика собственно процесс нужно запустить коммандой `run` или `r`

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/thr
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7ffff6ee0700 (LWP 27964)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff66df700 (LWP 27965)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff5ede700 (LWP 27966)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff56dd700 (LWP 27967)]
my
hello
ro
world
.......
```

Процесс можно в любой момент приостановить `SIGINT`'ом или, другими словами, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

## Определение обстановки

После остановки в произвольной точке стоит посмотреть, где же мы находимся, для этого есть команды `backtrace` (`b`) и `info threads` (`i th`)

```
Thread 1 "thr" received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00007ffff729a93d in pthread_join () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff729a93d in pthread_join () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007ffff7ab7537 in std::thread::join() () from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.4.0/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x0000555555555310 in main () at thr.cpp:13
(gdb) i th
  Id   Target Id         Frame
* 1    Thread 0x7ffff7f7d740 (LWP 28093) "thr" 0x00007ffff729a93d in pthread_join () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  2    Thread 0x7ffff6ee0700 (LWP 28097) "thr" 0x00007ffff72a4e4d in nanosleep () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  3    Thread 0x7ffff66df700 (LWP 28098) "thr" 0x00007ffff72a4e4d in nanosleep () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  4    Thread 0x7ffff5ede700 (LWP 28099) "thr" 0x00007ffff72a4e4d in nanosleep () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  5    Thread 0x7ffff56dd700 (LWP 28100) "thr" 0x00007ffff72a4e4d in nanosleep () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
```

Как видно, gdb сейчас находится в контексте `pthread_join()` основного потока.

## Смена кадра стека и печать переменной

Чтобы распечатать переменную (`print`) нужно переключиться на кадр, в котором она находится для этого есть команда `frame` (`f`), заодно можно посмотреть листинг(`list`):

```
(gdb) f 2
#2  0x0000555555555310 in main () at thr.cpp:13
13           std::thread([](){ while(true) { std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(700)); std::cout << "ro\n";}}).join();
(gdb) l
8                    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds(700));
9                    std::cout << "hello\n";}
10                   }).detach();
11           std::thread([](){ while(true) { std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(600)); std::cout << "my\n";}}).detach();
12           std::thread([](){ while(true) { std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(900)); std::cout << "world\n";}}).detach();
13           std::thread([](){ while(true) { std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(700)); std::cout << "ro\n";}}).join();
14      }
(gdb) p i
$1 = 3
```

где двойка в `frame 2` — это номер интересующего кадра в выводе `bt`.

## Пошаговая отладка потока

Чтобы по-шагам отлаживать конкретный поток нужно переключить gdb в его контекст командой `thread` (`thr`):

```
(gdb) thread 2
[Switching to thread 2 (Thread 0x7ffff6ee0700 (LWP 28097))]
#0  0x00007ffff72a4e4d in nanosleep () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
```

У каждого потока свой стек, поэтому не лишним будет снова посмотреть `backtrace` и, по необходимости, перейти в нужный кадр.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff72a4e4d in nanosleep () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000555555556aa7 in std::this_thread::sleep_for<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000l> > (__rtime=...) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.4.0/include/g++-v6/thread:323
#2  0x0000555555555140 in <lambda()>::operator()(void) const (__closure=0x55555576bc28) at thr.cpp:8
#3  0x0000555555556524 in std::_Bind_simple<main()::<lambda()>()>::_M_invoke<>(std::_Index_tuple<>) (this=0x55555576bc28) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.4.0/include/g++-v6/functional:1391
#4  0x0000555555556394 in std::_Bind_simple<main()::<lambda()>()>::operator()(void) (this=0x55555576bc28) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.4.0/include/g++-v6/functional:1380
#5  0x0000555555556292 in std::thread::_State_impl<std::_Bind_simple<main()::<lambda()>()> >::_M_run(void) (this=0x55555576bc20) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.4.0/include/g++-v6/thread:197
#6  0x00007ffff7ab724e in ?? () from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.4.0/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x00007ffff7299657 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#8  0x00007ffff6fd9c5f in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

После этого можно отлаживать поток привычным способом с помощью `next`/`step` (`n`/`s`):

```
(gdb) n
Single stepping until exit from function nanosleep,
which has no line number information.
my
world
ro
std::this_thread::sleep_for<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000l> > (__rtime=...) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.4.0/include/g++-v6/thread:328
328           }
(gdb)
my
world
ro
<lambda()>::operator()(void) const (__closure=0x55555576bc28) at thr.cpp:9
9                    std::cout << "hello\n";}
(gdb)
my
ro
world
hello
7                    ++i;
(gdb)
my
world
ro
8                    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds(700));
(gdb)
world
my
ro
my
ro
9                    std::cout << "hello\n";}
(gdb)
my
world
ro
hello
7                    ++i;
(gdb)
my
world
ro
8                    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds(700));
(gdb) p i
$2 = 5
```

Стоит упомянуть пару замечаний:

- Ради пошаговый отладки код был слегка переформатирован, как видно в листинге выше.
- Касательно многопоточных приложений: при возврате управления процессу по `n` запускаются сразу все потоки, поэтому можно видеть дополнительный вывод почти после каждой комманды.

К последующему прочтению/просмотру рекомендую, как минимум, букварь «[Отладка с помощью GDB](https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/gdb/)»

Comment: почему нужно делать именно frame 2? frame 3 выдает непонятки

Comment: @xperious, цифра это номер интересующего frame'а в выводе `bt`; YMMV

Comment: хм, info thread... bt... frame 2... thread 2... print i - пишет, что нету i в контексте

Comment: @xperious, у каждого потока свой стек, поэтому сначала thread, а уж потом bt итд:  info thread... thread 2... bt... frame <из_bt>...  print i

Comment: воо, за разъяснения спасибо... а то букварь... вот буквально последовательность команд надо было только понять... кучу статеек перечитал - так и не понял... а тут на одном примере понятнее стало гораздо