# Как дебажить asyncio корутины с GDB?

Tags: python, python-3.x, отладка, asyncio, gdb

[Есть расширение](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb), которое позволяет использовать GDB для дебага Питонячих процессов, я его установил и попробовал использовать на моём веб-приложении на aiohttp. Но, какие бы запросы там не выполнялись, в консоли всегда отображается самый базовый стэк вызовов, без какой-либо полезной информации:

```bsh
(gdb) py-bt
Traceback (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/selectors.py", line 468, in select
    fd_event_list = self._selector.poll(timeout, max_ev)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1739, in _run_once
    event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 539, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 571, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/aiohttp/web.py", line 433, in run_app
    reuse_port=reuse_port))
  File "./my-server/main.py", line 98, in <module>
    web.run_app(app_main, host=host, port=port)
```

Вероятно это следствие того, что asyncio создаёт свой стэк вызовов каждой корутине.

Мне очень важно иметь возможность смотреть внутренности процесса для дебага нагруженного веб-приложения. Как можно посмотреть стэк вызовов и прерывать/продолжать корутины с GDB?

Comment: Про питоньи радости сказать ничего не могу и про детали реализации asyncio я тоже не так много знаю, но *<здесь много «если»>* возможно можно просто получить список потоков с помощью `info threads` и перейти на нужный с помощью `thread N`, о том как с этим работать в нормальных языках я уже писал тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/771275/gdb-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/771289#771289

Comment: @Fat-Zer там же системные потоки? Питон однопоточный, поэтому вряд ли прокатит... хотя по идее принцип работы должен быть очень схож.

Comment: опять, же я не знаю, что из себя представляет asyncio... если это просто диспетчер событий, с циклом, то решение почти наверняка не поможет, да и gdb тоже... если он запускает каждую корутину в отдельном полноценном потоке, то поможет... если это менеджер thread pool'а worker'ов (затрудняюсь сейчас с русскими терминами), как в каком-нить Go, то частично может и помочь, но вряд ли...

Comment: @Fat-Zer это цикл который смотрит системные 
select(2) и дергает колбэки

Comment: @AivanF. каждый await кладется на стек run_forever - это как разворот рекурсии в цикл. тоесть вызывающая функция лежит не выше, а рядом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После долгих поисков удалось найти альтернативное решение, утилита **py-spy**! В отличие от gdb, ей не нужен запуск целевого процесса на специальной сборке Питона, а также она не испытывает трудностей при работе с асинхронными функциями. Простой пример использования:

```bsh
pip install py-spy

# Получить стэки вызовов активных потоков:
py-spy dump --pid 1

# Смотреть выполняющиеся функции в реалтайме:
py-spy top --pid 1
```

Подробное описание можно найти здесь: https://github.com/benfred/py-spy

Важное для некоторых окружений замечание: как и gdb, для использования внутри Докера этой утилите нужен включенный флаг `SYS_PTRACE`.